# Oracle ODBC connection via MS Access- Able to connect to one database but not another

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

For some reason I am able to connect to the first database (see below) but not the second one on MS Access. Here is tnsnames.ora

```
FC_P.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (LOAD_BALANCE=off) 
   (FAILOVER=on)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = fcp) (PORT = 1575))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = fcp2)(PORT = 1575))
   )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = xtr)
    )
  )

mac_P.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (LOAD_BALANCE=off) 
   (FAILOVER=on)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xfcscan) (PORT = 1521))
   )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = xcom_o)
    )
  )
```

For the successful connection, I entered FC_P.WORLD into TNS service name and my login credentials and was able to connect. However, using mac_P.WORLD and those respective credentials did not work. What is happening?

Running

```
SELECT * FROM v$VERSION;
```

shows that one of the Database versions has the attribute: "TNS for Solaris", whereas the other one has "TNS for Linux"

Comment: (SERVICE_NAME = xcom_o) vs (SID..)

Comment: what is the difference between service_name and SID, and how can I circumvent this difference to connect anyways?

Comment: I don't know enough about your environment, but service_name <> SID although they can be the same. Oracle SID is the unique name that uniquely identifies your instance/database where as Service name is the TNS alias that you give when you remotely connect to your database and this Service name is recorded in Tnsnames.ora file. Just go ahead and try changing SERVICE_NAME to SID.

Comment: it didn't work but thanks for the information

Comment: Are the two DB's of different release?

Comment: Are the DB's running on different character sets?

Comment: I'm not sure for both, how can I check?

Comment: Check with `SELECT * FROM v$VERSION;` and `SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';
`

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use? The driver from Microsoft (`Microsoft ODBC for Oracle`) or from Oracle (`Oracle in OraClient11g_home1` or similar)

Comment: the queries returned identical output for both databases

Comment: I am not certain about which one it is, but the name is ODAC122010_x64.zip. On deeper inspection, it's the Oracle driver.

Comment: Are you sure? This would mean your MS Access is also 64 Bit - it that true?

Comment: In File-> Account, it says the Access is 64-bit. EDIT: one of the Database versions has the attribute: "TNS for Solaris", whereas the other one has "TNS for Linux"

Comment: Solaris is Oracle's OS they purchased from Sun Microsystems, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Please provide an example of your listener.ora file.

Comment: where is the file located? a search yielded nothing

Comment: $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin is where it should be, but check your TNS_ADMIN variable too. If you're using Solaris, maybe it's in /var/opt/oracle

Comment: the only thing in that folder is tnsnames.ora

Comment: Please run the following and copy the results here: lsnrctl status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158023/discussion-between-jacob-barnes-and-machump).